# IBM Data Studio web console - Job manager - db2 clp script - How stop execution at first error

Tags: db2

i want to migrate my taks (DB2 command script) from task center (control center) to data studio web console job manager. My question is in "db2 clp script", how to configure to "stop execution at first return code that is a failure" like task center?
This setting does not existting in job manager or is there another way to do it?

Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at IBM Data Server Manager?

The Web Console Component of Data Studio is deprecated from Data Studio V4.1.2 onward. https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27038176

IBM Data Server Manager is the intended replacement for Data Studio Web Console.

Comment: Thanks Paul,

I didn´t know that the data studio was deprecated but I test the data server manager and this setting does not existting. In this part of Job manager they are very equal..

Comment: Can you pass parameters to the clp command? If so `-s` will set "Stop execution on command error"  on

Comment: If not, you might need to raise a RFE for this https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/

Comment: Tks Paul, I test in begginer of the script of the job 
UPDATE COMMAND OPTIONS USING S ON; and he stop on the first error. In the next job it's need to put again in the scrip.